# Error restTemplate con Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, resttemplate

Estoy haciendo los test de cobertura con Junit en mi entorno de Springboot, la aplicación funciona perfectamente, el problema es cuando llega a la línea de restTemplate para llamar a otro servicio que falla el test.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ApplicationTestsCoverServiceImpl {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    MonitorService monitorService;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        Operative operative[] = new Operative[1];
        operative[0] = new Operative ();
        operative[0].setOperativeId("1A");
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://Api",
                Operative [].class)).thenReturn(operative);

        ResponseEntity<List<Operative >> operative2 = monitorService.getOperatives("edu");
        assertNotNull(operative2);
    }
```

El test es:

Mockeo un restTemplate para las llamadas y creo un bean de mi service.
Creo un objeto para la llamada de después y cuando el Mockito detecte que está llamando a una url, devuelva el objeto que creé anteriormente
Y finalmente compruebo que me devuelve algo que no sea nulo.

El código de la implementación es:

```
log.info(" ---> LogInfo: EMPIEZA el método");
String url = this.replaceContent(this.urlBase +  user);

log.info(" ---> LogInfo: Se llamará a: " + url);
Operative[] operative = this.restTemplate.getForObject(url, Operative[].class);

log.info(" ---> LogInfo: El usuario tiene: " + operative.length + " operativas.");
List<Operative> list = new ArrayList<Operative>();
list.add(operative);
return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
```

El código de la ejecución cuando hace el test llega hasta:

```
"log.info(" ---> LogInfo: Se llamará a: " + url);"
```

Y ya revienta.

Parece que no puede hacer el restTemplate desde la parte de la implementación ...

Comment: Ya probste ponerle los matchers? `Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(anyString() , any(Operative [].class))`

Comment: Eso está en la 4º línea del código...

Comment: no tiene matchers sino valores literales, por eso te lo digo, compara bien

Comment: es cierto, muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito funciona usando matchers en vez de los datos reales para evitar errores de comparación (el típico problema de == vs equals)

[Aquí](https://www.journaldev.com/21876/mockito-argument-matchers-any-eq) podrás hallar una lista de argument matchers con ejemplos.

Para tu caso en particular te recomiendo estos:

- anyString()
- any(Class)

Con el primero se verifica que se acepte alguna cadena, con el segundo que se envíe un elemento de tupo arreglo de objetos `Operative`.

```
 Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(anyString() , any(Operative [].class))
```